# How to align title in listitem when not showing subtitle into listview

Tags: android, layout

I have listview and a two textview "title" and "subtitle" as a part of listitem. Now in some listitems i am only displaying only "title" and not "subtitle", in those case how to align "title" in center ? Below is screenshot and xml code

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18sp" 
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="13sp" 
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lefticons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/righticons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Programatically I tried setting setMargins but it is messing up. Any other solutions ?

```
if (ei.getTitle().contentEquals("TV Results")) {
                    rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
                    leftimageicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    subtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)title.getLayoutParams();
                    params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
                    title.setLayoutParams(params);

                }
```

Full getView code :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        final Item i = items.get(position);
        if (i != null) {
            if(i.isSection()){
                SectionItem si = (SectionItem)i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);

                v.setOnClickListener(null);
                v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                v.setLongClickable(false);

                final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());
            }else{
                EntryItem ei = (EntryItem)i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry_settings, null);
                final TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
                final TextView subtitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_summary);
                final ImageView rightimageicon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.righticons);
                final ImageView leftimageicon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.lefticons);

                if (title != null) 
                    title.setText(ei.getTitle());
                if(subtitle != null)
                    subtitle.setText(ei.getSubtitle());

                if (ei.getTitle().contentEquals("Weekly Activity Status")) {
                    rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
                    leftimageicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    subtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)title.getLayoutParams();
                    params.setMargins(7, 7, 7, 7); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
                    title.setLayoutParams(params);
                    //rightimageicon.setLayoutParams(params);
                } 
                else if (ei.getTitle().contentEquals("TV Results")) {
                    rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
                    leftimageicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    subtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)title.getLayoutParams();
                    params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
                    title.setLayoutParams(params);

                } 

                else if (ei.getTitle().contentEquals("MI App")) {

                    if(prefs.getRoamDataAllowed(context)){
                        rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.switch_on);
                        button01pos = 1;
                    }else{
                        rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.switch_off);
                        button01pos = 0;
                    }

                    rightimageicon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (button01pos == 0) {
                                rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.switch_on);
                                button01pos = 1;
                            } else if (button01pos == 1) {
                                rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.switch_off);
                                button01pos = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    leftimageicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    subtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)title.getLayoutParams();
                    params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
                    title.setLayoutParams(params);
                } 

                else if (ei.getTitle().contentEquals("MI VPN")) {
                    if (vpnenableboolean && currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH && !prefs.getTunInterfaceNotAvilableStatus(context)) { 
                        rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.switch_on);
                        leftimageicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        subtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)title.getLayoutParams();
                        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
                        title.setLayoutParams(params);

                        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH && !prefs.getTunInterfaceNotAvilableStatus(context)) {

                            if (SettingsActivity.profile_name != null) {

                                try {

                                    current_state = defaultprefs.getString("currentstate",
                                            "DISCONNECTED");

                                    if (current_state.equalsIgnoreCase("CONNECTED")
                                            && OpenVPNService.current_state
                                                    .equalsIgnoreCase("CONNECTED")) {
                                        rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.switch_on);
                                    } else {
                                        rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.switch_off);
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.switch_off);
                                }

                            } else {
                                rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.switch_off);

                            }

                        }
                    }



                } 

                else if (ei.getTitle().contentEquals("Facebook")) {

                    leftimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.facebook);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)title.getLayoutParams();
                    params.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
                    title.setLayoutParams(params);
                    if(!prefs.getFbTokenStatus(context)){
                        subtitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                    }else{
                        subtitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
                    }
                } 

                else if (ei.getTitle().contentEquals("Twitter")) {

                    leftimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.twitter);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)title.getLayoutParams();
                    params.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
                    title.setLayoutParams(params);
                    if(!prefs.getTwTokenStatus(context)){
                        subtitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                    }else{
                        subtitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        rightimageicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    rightimageicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    leftimageicon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
        return v;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="8dp">

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lefticons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18sp" 
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="13sp" 
            />
    </LinearLayout>



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/righticons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change inner `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **RelativeLayout**,title will fill the RelativeLayou when subtitle is gone.

Answer (score 0):

*didn't work out any solution I solved by this way:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/header_blue"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/subtitle_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Sub title"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

just try by removing text view

**`android:visibility="gone"`**